# No G-SYNC option in NVIDIA-SETTINGS?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 16.04, nvidia-settings

I have no G-SYNC options available in the nvidia-settings.

I have got a g-sync ready laptop with a NVIDIA GTX970M and am currently running 16.04LTS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I have gotten a little further (I think).

In the xorg.conf it states that no modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select" will be used as the requested mode.

I think there is something wrong with my EDID? Nvidia does not give me any screen resolution options apart from 1920x1080 at 60Hz..

Any help or info would be greatly appreciated!